# Scrape all used javascripts on a website using python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, google-analytics, screen-scraping

I am looking for a way to determine the name of all javascripts that are used on a website. It is not suitable to simply download the website's sourcecode using the request lib as this will not yield all javascripts that are used. 
For example the website https://www.grantthornton.global/en/ uses Google Analytics (analytics.js) as one can see using chrome's "Network" tab for all used javascripts.

However you can not determine the usage of analytics.js through the sourcode alone as analytics.js is loaded through the google-tag-manager.
My current approach is to load the Website using selenium and to record all data through browsermob-proxy. I can then check for all javascripts that have been accessed by checking the urls (example: https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js)
Is there any better way than this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from browsermobproxy import Server
import pprint, time

server = Server("browsermob-proxy-2.1.4\\bin\\browsermob-proxy")
server.start()
proxy = server.create_proxy({'captureHeaders': True, 'captureContent': True, 'captureBinaryContent': True})

service_args = ["--proxy=%s" % proxy.proxy, '--ignore-ssl-errors=yes']
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS("phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs", service_args=service_args)
proxy.new_har()
driver.get('URL GOES HERE')
time.sleep(3)
all_requests = [entry['request']['url'] for entry in proxy.har['log']['entries']]

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
pp.pprint(proxy.har)
```

**EDIT:**
Solution based on Florent B's approach. The webdriver has been replaced by the chrome webdriver which needs to be downloaded instead of phantomjs:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pprint, time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.URLGOESHERE.com")
time.sleep(3)
scripts = driver.execute_script("""return window.performance.getEntriesByType("resource").filter(e => e.initiatorType === 'script').map(e => e.name.match(/.+\/([^?]+)/)[1]);""")
driver.close()

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
pp.pprint(scripts)
```

Comment: Can you share your code trials?

Comment: Sorry, i prematurely posted the question; the code is attached now.

Comment: Are you wondering if your specific code can be improved (probably yes) or if your methodology is sound  ?

Comment: Both, it seems to be very inefficient and I can imagine that lots of edge-cases have not been considered. Is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also get all the downloaded scripts via the [`window.performance`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance) API :

```
scripts = driver.execute_script("""
  return window.performance.getEntriesByType("resource")
    .filter(e => e.initiatorType === 'script')
    .map(e => e.name);
  """)
print(scripts)
```

Comment: This yields a list of all URLs that provide javascripts. Not the name of the scripts themselves. However this can be transformed easily as the javascript's name is the end of the URL. Thank you for the way more elegant solution.

Comment: simply replace `e.name` by `e.name.match(/.+\/([^?]+)/)[1]` to get the name only.